How to interpret the additive term in torque formula?
Torque formula for a body subjected to a force is: $\vec{M}$ = $\frac{\mathbb d\vec{L}}{\mathbb dt}$ + $\vec{v}_o$ $\times$ $\vec{p}$; where $\vec{M}$ is the torque, $\vec{L}$ is the angular momentum, $\vec{v}_o$ is the velocity of the pole O (from which we evaluate the position of the application point of the force) and $\vec{p}$ is the momentum.
I don't fully understand, from the physical point of view, the term $\vec{v}_o$ $\times$ $\vec{p}$. If I have a rotating disk on a 2D plan and I consider a point on it, why should his traslation modify the torque in that point?

Try to have a look here https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/dynamics_newton_eoms_points.html where the equations are derived for a system of points. For an interpretation: the motion of the pole (geometric object) makes the angular momentum and moments w.r.t. that pole change, since you're changing distances and arms used for the computation of those quantities

What if the pole has a velocity and the application point of the force moves along with the pole at the same velocity (and so the distances and the arms don't change)? @basics

In that case, you have no change in the external moment, but you could have only the contribution of the relative motion of the pole w.r.t. the center of mass of the system

The motion of a pole $H$, even for a free system, makes the angular momentum  $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_H$ w.r.t. that pole change in general, since you're moving the point w.r.t. you're computing $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_H$.
Since your doubt doesn't concern the external moment, let's focus on a free system, $\boldsymbol{M}_H^{ext} = \boldsymbol{0}$, governed by
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{\Gamma}}_H = - \dot{\boldsymbol{x}}_H \times \boldsymbol{Q} \ ,$$
Example 1 - Point in uniform motion and moving pole
Let's focus on a simple example first. Consider a point mass $m_P$ moving in a 2D plane, in a constant $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ direction, with constant velocity $\mathbf{v}_P = v_P \, \boldsymbol{\hat{x}}$, with the law of motion
$$\boldsymbol{x}_P(t) = \mathbf{v}_P \, t \ ,$$
with no net force acting on it and constant momentum $\mathbf{Q} = m \mathbf{v}_P = m v_P \mathbf{\hat{x}}$.
Let's then take a pole $H$ moving along a orthogonal direction $\boldsymbol{\hat{y}}$, s.t.
$$\boldsymbol{x}_H(t) = v_H \, t \, \mathbf{\hat{y}} \ .$$
Let's evaluate now the angular momentum of the point mass $P$ w.r.t. H
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{\Gamma}_H & = (\mathbf{x}_P - \mathbf{x}_H) \times \mathbf{Q} = \\
& = ( v_P \mathbf{\hat{x}} - v_H \mathbf{\hat{y}}) t \times m v_P \mathbf{\hat{x}} = \\
& = m v_H v_P t \mathbf{\hat{z}}  \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
and evaluate the time derivative
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{\mathbf{\Gamma}}_H &= m v_H v_P \mathbf{\hat{z}} = \\
& = -(v_H \boldsymbol{\hat{y}}) \times (m v_P \mathbf{\hat{x}}) = \\
& = - \dot{\mathbf{x}}_H \times \mathbf{Q} \ . \end{aligned}$$
